# Get if a rolling window is increasing or decreasing

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a panda's `DataFrame` and I would like to calculate for each interval of a moving window along one of its columns whether the data inside that interval is increasing or decreasing. For increasing/ decreasing I mean to calculate the sign of the last element minus the first element.

For now I have this solution:

```
sign = data['col'].rolling('5d').apply(lambda x: np.sign(x[-1] - x[0]))
```

The problem of this implementation is that it's extremely slow for long Series. Do you have a solution that uses builtin, optimised functions?

Comment: Can you please provide an example input and expected output. It is not clear to me what do you need to apply this calculation to every window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only getting the first value and last value different by using a memory cost `rolling` function which will reduce the speed of whole process , Here I am using `merge_asof`

```
s=df[['COL']].shift(4,freq='D')
s=pd.merge_asof(df,s,left_index=True,right_index=True,tolerance=pd.Timedelta('5d'),direction='forward')
np.sign(s['COL_x']-s['COL_y'])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. The first line should be `s = df[['val']].shift(4, freq='D')`, i.e. *4* instead of *5*, to yield the same result.

Comment: Timed it:

%timeit -r 7 -n 100 channel_data['val'].rolling('{}d'.format(window)).apply(lambda x: np.sign(x[-1] - x[0]), raw=True)
9.09 ms ± 122 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

This solution:
2.45 ms ± 30.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

If your 'col' values are uniformly sampled you can apply something similar to below.

```
col = pandas.Series([1,-1,0,3,5,21,7,4,67,4,3,6,8,5,4])
sign = np.sign(col.values[0:-5] - col.values[5:])
```

Essentially you take the first N-window_len and subtract the last N-window_len (here I assume you have a data point for each day). vector operation would be significantly faster than using rolling